# Computing the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^3x^{3/4})/(1+n^4x^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^3 x^{3/4}}{ 1 + n^4 x^2}.$$

The overall goal is to find the uniform limit of a sequence of functions, or show that the sequence does not converge uniformly.

**My attempt:**

I know that I will treat $x$ as a constant here and I can divide both the numerator and denominator by the largest power of $n$ in the denominator, which is $n^4$. but then what? I want to find to what function the given sequence of functions converges uniformly, could anyone help me in doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointwise limit is $0$. If the convergence is uniform then  the expression must tend  to $0$ even when you make $x$ depend on $n$.

If you put $x_n=n^{-4/5}$ the expression tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. This implies that the convergence is not uniform.

Proof of the fact that pointwise limit is $0$: if $x=0$ this is obvious. If $x \neq 0$ divide numerator and denominator by $n^{4}$ and take the limit.

Comment: I am sorry for this trivial question but how did you find the pointwise limit? did you divide by the largest power of $n$ in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: @Smart I have edited my answer.

Comment: So the pointwise limit depends on the domain of $x$?

Comment: @Smart It is $0$ for every real number $x$. But for the proof you consider the cases $x=0$ and $x \neq 0$ separately.

Comment: what theorem did you use to prove that this pointwise limit is zero? is it the Weirasstrass $M$ test? what makes you divide the proof into cases depending on $x$, I am just forgetting the theorems that lead to this?

Comment: @Smart After dividing each term by $n^{4}$ just take limit for each term and you will get $\farc 0 {0+x^{2}}=0$. I am just using the theorem about limits of sums and limits of ratios. Things like M-test are used only for convergence of series, not for sequences.

Comment: Okay that is fine .... so it is just ordinary theorems .... thanks. Also,  if it is uniformly convergent the limit must be zero also as uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence ..... correct?

Answer (score 2):

As the power of $x$ in denominator is greater than nominator, they can't **uniformly** converge at $x=0$. If you want, you should exclude an interval around $x=0$ from domain.